# Control Databinding to View not ViewModel in MVVM scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, icommand

I've been working with the MVVM model for a week or so now and I think I have a handle on what should go where now. Note the "think" in that.

I have a single ViewModel that my view (MainWindow) binds to

```
_ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
this.DataContext = _ViewModel;
```

I have a few ICommands that do work within the ViewModel and subsequently the Model, which I'm fine with.

Now I initiate a few windows from my View (MainWindow) which I do in codebehind, as it's all purely view related stuff. I am trying to replicate the ICommand setup I have in the ViewModel in the View to simplify my life, or so I thought. I have the following commands set-up:

```
public ICommand comInitialiseWindows { get; private set; }

private bool _windowsactive = false;
public bool WindowsActive
{
    get { return _windowsactive; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _windowsactive, value); }
}
public bool comInitialiseWindows_CAN()
{
    return !_windowsactive;
}
private void comInitialiseWindows_DO()
{
    ... Code to do the window creation, etc.
}
```

I have this relay command in the MainWindow code:

```
comInitialiseWindows = new RelayCommand(() => comInitialiseWindows_DO(), comInitialiseWindows_CAN);
```

If I put this in the ViewModel it works a treat apart from the window creation stuff, but as it's View related I'm not surprised.

So the problem is the code doesn't run when I click the button. I'm guessing that the XAML is bound to the ViewModel, but I can't figure a way around this without setting the Binding for each button to the MainWindow in codebehind. I had assumed that the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
<Button x:Name="ribbutLayoutWindows"                                     
    Command="{Binding local:comInitialiseWindows}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding local:comInitialiseWindows_CAN}"/>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just not getting something somewhere. Or I'm trying to overcomplicate matters where a normal button click would have sufficed as it's View only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is "initiate a few windows" pure view related? your viewmodel contain the view logic, the view just visualize the viewmodel for the user. i use services which called from the viewmodel to initiate new dialog or windows. and btw you should check wether you need new windows or maybe just to switch the usercontrol for your mainview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

**Through the ViewModel**:
You could expose a Property on your ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    ICommand comInitialiseWindows  {get; set;}
}
```

And in your MainWindow:

```
MainViewModel vm = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
vm.comInitialiseWindows  = new RelayCommand(() => comInitialiseWindows_DO(), comInitialiseWindows_CAN);
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="ribbutLayoutWindows" Command="{Binding comInitialiseWindows}" />
```

Note: you don't need to bind the `IsEnabled` property. WPF will handle that for you and automatically call into the CanExecute-method of your ICommand.

**Through a DependencyProperty**

Declare this dependecyProperty in your code-behind:

```
public ICommand comInitialiseWindows
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty comInitialiseWindowsProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("comInitialiseWindows", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Assign a value in the code-behind:

```
comInitialiseWindows = new RelayCommand(() => comInitialiseWindows_DO(), comInitialiseWindows_CAN);
```

After that, you need to break out of your data-context in the XAML. First of all, give your Page a name:

```
<Window x:Class="Web_Media_Seeker_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Web_Media_Seeker_WPF"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="myWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

And then declare your binding as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="ribbutLayoutWindows" Command="{Binding comInitialiseWindows, ElementName=myWindow}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unless I'm mistaken in your first example the "_DO" would be in the ViewModel. I've tried that and got it to work fine, it's just that the window handling I need to be in the MainWindow code-behind. I've looked at the 2nd example, but it doesn't seem to work for me at all. I'm guessing where you put "MyPropertyProperty" this should be comInitialiseWindowsProperty, but the "_DO" code just doesn't trigger.

Comment: No, in the first example, the only thing in your VM is the property. The methods and the creation of the command are in the MainPage.

Comment: Ahhh. I will give that a try and see. In the 2nd example I'm getting a "cannot find source for binding" message in the output window, so there is obviously something amiss somewhere.

Comment: Sweeet. Thanks the 1st one worked right off the bat. Have my bool wrong somewhere tho 'cos the wrong button is disabled ;-) Thanks...